# Use a client credentials flow with Python Requests

Tags: python

For a project, I try to get a access token in Python using Request module.

It works with a GET method:

```
import requests, json

# Oauth API - GET call - Winnie project
access_token = requests.get("https://api.ebanking.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=27c5b286-62a6-45c7-beda-abbaea6eecf2&client_secret=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e").json()["access_token"]
```

But, not with a POST method:

```
import requests, json

data = {'grant_type':'client_credentials', 
        'client_id':'27c5b286-62a6-45c7-beda-abbaea6eecf2', 
        'client_secret':'6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e'} 

# Oauth API - POST call - Winnie project
access_token = requests.post(url = "https://api.ebanking.dev/oauth", data = data).json()["access_token"]
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read what's on-topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 10):

I had same problem, but when you are using authentication by client_credential you must encode the Autherization and put in order the headers and the body.

```
import base64, requests, sys


client_id = "client_id"
client_secret = "client_secret"

# Encode the client ID and client secret
authorization = base64.b64encode(bytes(client_id + ":" + client_secret, "ISO-8859-1")).decode("ascii")


headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Basic {authorization}",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
body = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}

response = requests.post("https://url.com", data=body, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```