# How to take take access tokens from oauth2

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, google-oauth, refresh-token

I'm having problems on taking the access token from the oauth2 platform with python.

Currently, that's what I'm using on my post request:

```
def token(self):
        client_id=ID_DO_CLIENTE
        client_secret=SECRET_TOKEN
        grant_type='client_credentials'

        response = requests.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
                                auth=(client_id, client_secret),
                                 data={'grant_type':grant_type,'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret})
        print(response.text)
```

This specific code is returning the following error:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
```

But I don't think the problem is the grant_type, since I've tried everything I've found online to solve this.

Anyway, if there's any info missing, please let me know. Please help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "error": "unsupported\_grant\_type" when trying to get a JWT by calling an OWIN OAuth secured Web Api via Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360349/getting-error-unsupported-grant-type-when-trying-to-get-a-jwt-by-calling-an)

Comment: you are using `auth` which is for basic auth.

try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36737820/16912753

Comment: I've tried both of these and did not succeed unfortunately. But just now I realized something: My application is supposed to do simple requests from a server, and not to authenticate users, for example. Is there some difference to how I am approaching this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code for reference:

```
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
  requests.post(token_url, 
    
      data=data,
      auth=(client_id, client_secret))
```

In the provided sample code, the data part is being sent incorrectly viz:

```
data={'grant_type':grant_type,'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret}
```

I think it should be this:

```
data={'grant_type':grant_type}
```

Adding the sample code which I am testing to verify the token generation logic:

```
client_id = '<value>'
client_secret = '<value>'
# This is optional
scope = '<uri>'

#Token generation step
#If scope is not defined above then remove it from this call
data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials','scope': scope}

access_token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=data, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, auth=(client_id, client_secret))

print (access_token_response.headers)
print (access_token_response.text)

tokens = json.loads(access_token_response.text)

print ("access token: " + tokens['access_token'])
```

Comment: It didn't help, unfortunatelly :(

But thank you anyway

Comment: Just added a sample code as well for reference.

Comment: I tried exactly your code and got a 302 response, but nothing on the response is the actual token. I will edit my answer to post the response text and body in general

Comment: Have you got this working?

Answer (score 0):

A valid request will also need these headers in order to send data in the correct format - I suspect JSON is sent by default, resulting in a malformed request:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded
Authorization: Basic [base 64 encoded client id and secret]
```

**TECHNIQUES**

Aim to use the curl tool to get the token first, to ensure the setup is right - as in [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/client-credentials/).

Also aim to trace the request via an [HTTP proxy tool](https://www.zyte.com/blog/python-requests-proxy/) to ensure that the wire message is being sent correctly.

These techniques will make you more productive when working with OAuth.

**CODE**

I had a search and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247433/use-a-client-credentials-flow-with-python-requests) seems to use the correct code, though you may be able to send the Authorization header like this:

```
auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass')
```